# react native компонент цикла

Tags: react-native

Друзья подскажите пожалйств с помощи чего можно рендерит циклы.
Например в react.js есть компонент For который позволяет массив легко отрозить на странице

```
<ul>
    <For each="item" in={props.items}>
        <li key={item.id}>
            {item.text}
        </li>
    </For>
</ul>
```

Я понимаю что механизм работы с нативными компонентами чуть другой нежеле с html тегами.
Но как имея некий массив, его отрендерить на экране
типо того

```
<View>
  <For each="item" in={this.state.items}>
   <Text>{item.text}</Text>
  </For>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать отдельный компонент для вывода списка, к примеру:

```
import React from 'react';

const ItemList = ({json}) => {
  const element = json.map(option => (
    <li key={option.id}>{option.text}</li>
  ));

  return (
    <ul>
      {element}
    </ul>
  );
}
```